# What's so important about the teddy bear in Taken 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, taken-2

In taken 2 there is a scene where they capture and torture [Jean-Claude](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0705005/) for information on Liam Neeson's whereabouts.

At first he refuses and says he will never tell until they bring out a teddy bear. What was so important to him about the teddy bear that made him give up the location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the intention was to tell him that if he didn't cooperate his kid (or kids?  I can't remember) would pay for his insubordination.

Answer (score 0):

The teddy bear symbolized his children (children's teddy bear).  The Albanians would harm his family (wife and kids) if he did not give up the information.